# What mandates the _start entrypoint (kernel, ld-linux.so, etc.)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, glibc, linker, ld

I know that ELF executable files need to have a visible `_start` subroutine where the execution begins. However, from what I can understand, the Kernel actually calls in `ld-linux.so` (or some other interpreter) and hand over the execution to it. So, my questions are:

1. Who mandates the `_start` entrypoint?
2. How does the kernel "call into" `ld-linux.so`? Does it have a stable API? A `_start` function, so to speak?

**Bonus Question**: It seems from a cursory glance that Glibc, `libdl` and `ld-linux.so` are all part of the same codebase and are tightly wound together (using each other's private interfaces). Does this mean that it is impossible to write a custom `libdl`-equivalent library to implement `dlopen`, etc.? Is it impossible for a non-C systems language to generate binaries that do not depend on `libc` and could still load `*.so` files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entry point is conventionally named `_start`, and is defined in the C runtime assembly routine that is linked into the executable. This short piece of code is responsible for setting up the stack, possibly calling C++ constructors, and finally calling `main`. The definitive answer to where a program starts execution is the `e_entry` value in the ELF header in the executable file. This value is set to point to `_start` by the linker.

You can see this by examining an executable program with `readelf -a progfile`.

Dynamic linking complicates matters a bit, since the dynamic linker is loaded and started first, with the responsibility of loading and linking the shared libraries the program needs. The dynamic linker is also specified in the executable file (it is called the "program interpreter".)

Lwn.net had an excellent two-part article on [How programs get run](https://lwn.net/Articles/630727/) ([part two](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/)), which I recommend reading if you really want to get into the details of this topic.

Comment: Thank you. I'll wait a while to see if any new answers come, then I'll mark yours correct.